# How to extract modify date from the EXIF?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

I tried the following code:

```
from PIL import Image

def get_exif(filename):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    image.verify()
    return image.getexif()

def get_exif_date(exif):
    return exif.get_ifd(0x0132)

ff = 'path/to/file.jpg'
image_exif = get_exif(ff)
print(str(image_exif))
image_date = get_exif_date(image_exif)
print(str(image_date))
```

it returns the following output:

```
{34853: 2068, 296: 2, 34665: 228, 271: 'Apple', 272: 'iPhone X', 305: '14.4.2', 274: 1, 306: '2021:05:02 17:27:18', 531: 1, 282: 72.0, 283: 72.0, 316: 'iPhone X'}
{}
```

So, [ModifyDate tag](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html) (306=0x0132) is here, but I can not extract it. Any idea why?

Comment: Does `image_exif[306]` work?

Comment: there's python library that utilize exiftool application. You might want to try it `pip install PyExifTool` https://pypi.org/project/PyExifTool/

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
import piexif

# change date in a image exif data
image = Image.open('image.jpg')  # open image
exif_dict = piexif.load(image.info['exif'])  # get info dict
print(exif_dict)  # check info dict structure
# if there are not exif data you could set a structure like this
if not exif_dict:
    exif_dict = {'0th': {}, 'Exif': {}, 'GPS': {}, 'Interop': {}, '1st': 
    {}, 'thumbnail': None}

new_date = b'2014:02:14 22:21:18'  # choose new date
exif_dict['Exif'][36867] = new_date  # this ->(['Exif'][36867])<- could be 
# different, check in your info dict structure
print(exif_dict)  # check new info dict structure
new_exif_data = piexif.dump(exif_dict)  # set new exif data
image.save('new_image.jpg', exif=new_exif_data)  # save a new image equal 
# to original with new exif data
```